# How to assign NSManagedObjectContext from AppDelegate to ViewControllers in TabBased application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

newbie type of question here.

Since XCode doesn't provide project template for TabBased application with Core Data, so I have to go cutting and pasting Core Data stack from other templates to my TabBased application.

This is how to assign `NSManagedObjectContext` object from `AppDelegate` to `MasterViewController` in Master-Detail application template:

```
// AppDelegate.m (Master-Detail template)

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = 
            (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    MasterViewController *controller = 
            (MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

How to assign `NSManagedObjectContext` from `AppDelegate` to ViewControllers in TabBased application?

Comment: I think it's not good idea to share AppDelegate. You should to create separate class (maybe singleton) with one Persistent Store Coordinator. And you may have own MOC for every controller.

Comment: Could you explain why it is not a good idea to share AppDelegate? By default there is only one AppDelegate on TabBased application template.

Comment: because you tabBarController or other controllers have no need to know about AppDelegate. It's OOP-ugly

Comment: @ValentinShamardin: I do not see a "shared AppDelegate" in this code. When the application is launched, the AppDelegate creates the managed object context (implicitly via `self.managedObjectContext`) and passes that forward to a view controller. The view controller does not access the AppDelegate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tab bar controller is the root view controller and
the "master view controller" is on the first tab:

```
UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)tbc.viewControllers[0];
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

**Update:** If the first tab uses a navigation controller, you just have to insert one step:

```
UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *nc = tbc.viewControllers[0];
YourViewController controller = (YourViewController *)nc.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: My application is a Tab-based application not a Master-Detail application. It has 5 ViewControllers.

Comment: @AnwarChandra: This is just an example. `tbc.viewControllers[0]` is the view controller on the first tab. You can adjust that to your needs.

Comment: The application was terminated when assigning `self.managedObjectContext` to `controller.managedObjectContext`. I already added (and synthesize) managedObjectContext on my viewcontroller and import viewcontroller header to AppDelegate.

Comment: I think your solution is correct. The issue was on accessing `self.managedObjectContext;`. I will try to figure out this issue by myself.

Comment: tbc.viewControllers[0] is an `UINavigationController` object.

Comment: you forgot to cast tbc.viewControllers[0] as (UINavigationController *)

Comment: @AnwarChandra: That line does not need a cast, because `tbc.viewControllers[0]` returns a generic `id`. But the `UITabBarController *tbc = ...` line needs a cast,  which I have fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property on your View Controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext
```

Then say, for example you want to assign this for all view controller. You can do it by looping through the viewControllers of the UITabBarController.

```
UITabbarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
for (UIViewController *viewController in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
    viewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
}
```

Comment: it won't be able to recognize the property `viewController.managedObjectContext`

Comment: Instead of criticizing, try it out first.

Comment: I did try it out. it says "Property 'managedObjectContext' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *':

Comment: Import your view controller to the App Delegate